# Mongodb aggregate on two collections based on geopoint

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have two collections

**person**

```
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": 42,
    "address": {
         "location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [12.3456, 78.9101]}
    }
}
```

**restaurant**

```
{
    "name": "Bistro",
    "type": ["Maxican", "Italian"],
    "location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [12.3555, 78.9333]} 
}
```

I've created spherical indexes on both collections

```
db.person.createIndex({"address.location": "2dsphere"})
db.restaurant.createIndex({"location": "2dsphere"})
```

Now I want to find all the restaurants near to a person using lat/long in both collections.
for e.g find all the restaurants within 10KM of a person. result will look like below

```
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": 42,
    "address": {
         "location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [12.3456, 78.9101]}
    },
    "nearby_restaurants": [{"name": "Bistro", "distance": 5.3}]  // this means bistro is 5.3 KM away from this person
}
```

Notice that, I'm only using `name` field from restaurant collection and an additional field `distance` which will be calculated after the query.

I want to do this for all person. so basically for each person, i have to scan the whole restaurant collection every time.
To achieve this I thought of using lookup with aggregate, something like below

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "restaurant",
            let: {"personPoint": "$address.location"},
            as: "nearby_restaurants",
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $geoNear: {
                        near: "$$personPoint",
                        spherical: true,
                        distanceField: "distance",
                        maxDistance: 10 * 1000,  // within 10 KM
                        distanceMultiplier: 0.001  // get the result in KM
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$location"
                },
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$nearby_restaurants",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    }
])
```

This doesnt work at all. I get this error: **$geoNear requires a 'near' option as an Array"**

I tried to look at different sources but couldnt understand and fix the error.

PS: If currently, it's not possible through lookups/aggregate, how can we achieve the same through looping over each person's document?

Comment: I doubt geospatial indexes can be used in the subquery. They just started to use indices for **some**  comparison in $match stage in v5 https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ with many strings attached.

Comment: @AlexBlex is it possible to achieve the same through the loop?